# Powerbuilder api test tools

Tags: api, testing, powerbuilder

I found a definition of a function in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sybase.public.powerbuilder.pbni/JwIgFnVFm6c

```
function boolean FNX_IsPowerObject(long hwnd) Library "PBVM100.dll"
```

but now I need the signature for these three functions:

```
function ? FNX_DataWindowGetItemDateTime(long hwnd, parm1, parm2, parm3)    
    Library "PBVM100.dll"              
function ? FNX_DataWindowGetItemNumber(long hwnd, parm1, parm2, parm3) 
    Library "PBVM100.dll"                
function ? FNX_DataWindowGetItemString(long hwnd, parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4)
    Library "PBVM100.dll"
```

I do not know the type of the function parameters. Someone knows?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess they would be the same as the equivalent PowerScript ones.

Why would you use an external function instead of the standard DataWindow methods GetItemDateTime, GetItemNumber, GetItemString? There may be a totally different way to do what you want if we knew why you wanted this.

Comment: I have to use AutoIt (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for it and only can use standard dll.